# Asynchronous content is not found after button click in Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, selenium-ide, selenium-grid

I have created a script in Selenium IDE that goes to this page: https://www.lexology.com/instructcounsel/find and presses the 'Example' button and then asserts that results are displayed for the search. This script runs without a problem but when I export as Java to Selenium GRID then the assert fails.

The image taken by screenshot.java shows that none of the search results have loaded:
[image]

I am expecting: [image]

This seems to be the case even if I add a wait for the element. I have tried also adding a js.executeScript but this hasn't helped. It looks like either the button is not being found and clicked or the asynchronous content is not loading.

Here is my exported script:

```
package com.lbr.testcases.lexology.experts.instruct_counsel;

import com.lbr.utils.Screenshot;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class instruct_counsel_example_anon {
  private WebDriver driver;
  JavascriptExecutor js;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://host.docker.internal:4444/wd/hub"), new ChromeOptions());
    js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    new HashMap<String, Object>();
  }
  @After
  public void tearDown() {
    Screenshot.TakeScreenshot(driver);
    driver.quit();
  }
  @Test
  public void searchinstructcounselexampleanon() {
    // GIVEN that I am an anonymous user on the Instruct Counsel page
    driver.get("https://www.lexology.com/instructcounsel/find");
    // WHEN I press the Example button
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='do-example-search']/button")).click();
    js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,579)");
    // adding a wait for the content to be displayed
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 60);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//h3[contains(.,\\\'3. Find your lawyer (746 matches found)\\\')]")));
    // THEN some example lawyers are displayed
    MatcherAssert.assertThat(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[contains(.,\'David Zetoony\')]")).getText(), is("David Zetoony"));
    MatcherAssert.assertThat(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[contains(.,\'3. Find your lawyer (746 matches found)\')]")).getText(), is("3. Find your lawyer (746 matches found)"));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// GIVEN that I am an anonymous user on the Instruct Counsel page
driver.get("https://www.lexology.com/instructcounsel/find");
// WHEN I press the Example button
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='do-example-search']/button")).click();
```

`driver.get` should wait for the page to load, but that doesn't mean the button is ready to be clicked (the page can 'load' just the JavaScript hasn't finished registering `onClick` events for example). Try adding a wait for `elementToBeClickable`. You can also try putting in `thread.sleep` to see if you're just going to fast. Just don't forget to replace them with waits conditions!

Comment: I have moved the elementToBeClickable wait:

 `driver.get("https://test1.lexology.com/instructcounsel/find");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='do-example-search']/button")));
    // WHEN I press the Example button
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='do-example-search']/button")).click();`

I still get the same issue.